# opening an internal site from salesforce via custom links

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm trying to open a internal folder on one of our servers from Salesforce by way of clicking on the custom links in the left nav. I have it working-ish , but am getting a blank IE pop-up.  the behavior that i want is that the user clicks the link, stays on the current page and the folder location opens up in a new window. the bug I have is that there is an unwanted IE pop-up. I'm guessing there's some issue with an IE window vs file-explorer window.

The way i'm implementing it is my content source= URL and the behavior is display in a new window.  the URL = 'file:///Z:\myServer'

any ideas?

**UPDATE** Here is a screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general syntax would be:

```
file:////myserver/dir
```

First try using all forward slashes in your URL.

I noticed the URL you posted has 3 forward slashes. Also instead of using the drive letter(Z:), can you use the full network path. i.e the actual path that the drive letter Z: is mapped to?

Generally, if the value of your URL is entered into IE and if that opens the folder, it should work here too. Can you check if this works first so that you know your path is alright.

Comment: the path is right. but when i put it into IE ( Z:\COMPANY_SECRETS\PASSWORD_IS_QWERTY_SHH_DONT_TELL), a file manager window pops up with the directory. The IE window remains blank

Comment: Actually that would be default IE behavior. File system paths are opened in Windows Explorer while the IE tab/window will be blank.

Comment: That's kind of ugly.... is there a way to supress the IE window being opened up for all the users?

Comment: Try opening the link in an iframe instead? You'd have to use a home page component instead of a side bar link.

Answer (score 1):

Did you specify `target="blank"` in the link? If not give it go, if you did, try without it. Different browsers behave in different ways when accessing files, I've seen similar things in Firefox when downloading a file from Salesforce — I get left with a blank new window.

Comment: i'm not using javascript, i'm using the gui